# Relationship objects from the current object

Tags: dynamic-soql, relationships

I have 3 objects A, B and C. And B and C have lookup to A. I want to find all the objects which have lookup to the object A. I am able to get all the Child Relationships (using `schemaMap.get('A').getDescribe().getChildRelationships()`) where the object A is having relationship. I need all the objects which have relationship to A object. Please help me how can I all the objects which have relation ship to the selected object. Because I want to set the selected object as a base object and want to create a dynamic SOQL query using fields of the related objects. eg: Select B.name, C.employee From A Where Id = 34852893549. If anyone have any idea please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Code to  create and execute the dynamic SOQL would look something like this:

```
Id objectAId = ...;
for (ChildRelationship cr : schemaMap.get('A').getDescribe().getChildRelationships()){
    DescribeSObjectResult d = cr.getChildSObject().getDescribe();
    if (d.isQueryable()) {
        Map<String, SObjectField> fs = d.fields.getMap();
        List<String> fieldNames = new List<String>(fs.keySet());
        String soql = ''
                + ' select ' + String.join(fieldNames, ',')
                + ' from ' + String.valueOf(cr.getChildSObject())
                + ' where ' + String.valueOf(cr.getField()) + ' = :objectAId';
        List<SObject> children = Database.query(soql);
        // Do something with the results
    }
}
```

Useful references: [ChildRelationship Instance Methods](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/Content/apex_Schema_ChildRelationship_instance_methods.htm) and [Using Field Tokens](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_field_tokens.htm).